liquibase execute-sql --sql-file no generate output in sentence select multiline
when execute liquibase from file sql in multiline, dont be able to get the output
Command executed:
liquibase execute-sql --sql-file=scripts/scripts.sql --output-file=validation-results.csv
cat scripts/scripts.sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE rownum < 100
;
obtained output:
cat validation-results.csv
Successfully Executed: SELECT * FROM table
WHERE rownum < 100
expected output: output from query executed
it's work it only if the sentence sql is setting in a single multiline, example:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE rownum < 100;
In this case, I be able to get all data consulted

When you run it in a single line, what's your command line?

I am having the exact same error, I am wondering if it might be a bug of the recent version I am using 4.28.0
